# Returning objects from WebAPI to Flex

Tags: apache-flex, asp.net-web-api

I'm a Flex newbie, and I'm writing an MXML application that will receive information from a WebAPI service and display it.

So far I've managed to achieve this with a simple string, but if I try to return a complex object, it returns null.

Here's my code, it's a very simple form:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:acrs_surveys="services.acrs_surveys.*"
    xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*"
    minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
        </s:layout>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                GetSurveyResult.token = acrs_surveys.GetSurvey(itemidTextInput.text);
            }

            protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                survey.SurveyId = surveyIdTextInput.text;
                survey.Title = titleTextInput.text;
            }

            protected function assignSurveyResult(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                survey = event.result as Survey;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="GetSurveyResult" result="assignSurveyResult(event)"/>
        <valueObjects:Survey id="survey"/>
        <acrs_surveys:Acrs_surveys id="acrs_surveys" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true" />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Form defaultButton="{button}">
        <s:FormItem label="Itemid">
            <s:TextInput id="itemidTextInput"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:Button id="button" label="GetSurvey" click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:Form>
    <s:Form defaultButton="{button2}">
        <s:FormHeading label="Survey"/>
        <s:FormItem label="Questions">
            <s:Label id="QuestionsLabel" text="Questions_type[]"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="SurveyId">
            <s:TextInput id="surveyIdTextInput" text="{survey.SurveyId}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Title">
            <s:TextInput id="titleTextInput" text="{survey.Title}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:Button id="button2" label="Submit" click="button2_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:Form>
</s:Application>
```

The code was mostly generated by Flash Builder's wizards. The "Survey" class was generated by the Generate Service Call wizard, and contains three properties - a GUID, a Title, and a list of Question objects, which have also been defined by the same wizard.

When I run the code, no error occurs, and according to the Network Monitor, the call is made successfully and the data is returned. However, when I break the code in assignSurveyResult and check the survey object, the result is null.

If I change the code to use a WebAPI call which returns only the survey title as a string, it works fine. It appears to be only objects that won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tracing through the Flex source code, I found the solution. It turns out that the client proxy code generated by Flash Builder had set itself up to deserialize my XML data as JSON, with the result that the deserialized data appeared as "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", which could not be converted to an object.

When using the Generate Service Call wizard, a package is generated, which in my case is called "services.acrs_surveys". In this package is a "_Super_Acrs_surveys()" class, which declares two serializers in the header:

```
private static var serializer0:JSONSerializationFilter = new JSONSerializationFilter();
private static var serializer1:XMLSerializationFilter = new XMLSerializationFilter();
```

The constructor of this class sets which serializer will be used:

```
 operation = new mx.rpc.http.Operation(null, "GetSurvey");
 operation.url = "Get/{itemid}";
 operation.method = "GET";
 argsArray = new Array("itemid");
 operation.argumentNames = argsArray;         
 operation.serializationFilter = serializer0;
 operation.properties = new Object();
 operation.properties["urlParamNames"] = ["itemid"];
 operation.resultType = valueObjects.Survey;
 operations.push(operation);
```

Note that `operation.serializationFilter` is set to `serializer0`, which is the JSON serializer, even though the data for this operation is actually XML. It appears that the wizard didn't correctly detect the data type, hence the problem.

I changed the serializer to serializer1, and now my code works.

Interestingly the operation that only returned a string in XML was correctly detected, which is why it worked, as mentioned in my question.